# ERROR: install_parse_failed_manifest_malformed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I keep getting this error every time I try to emulate the app. I have no idea about what is going on.. Changed the package name so it wouldnt contain capital letters but that did not work..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.intelnuc.turism_app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.android.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" />
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".activitys.main_activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I have a folder named activitys for sorting purposes..

```
<activity
            android:name=".activitys.navigationPage"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.main_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.accountCreation"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.main_activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.accInfo"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.navigationPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.newPlace"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.navigationPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.mostPopular"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.navigationPage" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activitys.detailedActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.navigationPage" />
        <activity android:name=".activitys.myTools"
            android:parentActivityName=".activitys.navigationPage"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: try using a smaller package name: com.intelnuc.turismapp. This should work!!

Comment: How do I shorten the package? I know how to rename it, but not shorten it. Nice cat btw:)

Comment: Full error message `Installation failed with message INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl2057822491.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #33): <meta-data> requires an android:value or android:resource attribute.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?`

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells us: meta-data requires an android:value or android:resource attribute.

My guess are you don't provide the FileProvider with information on were to store files on the unit. See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

```
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" //<-- this is missing />
```

And then you need a corresponding xml file that tells were your files should be located (xml/file_paths.xml).

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_images" path="images/"/>
    <files-path name="my_docs" path="docs/"/>
</paths>
```